# How to use "xphoto_WhiteBalancer.balanceWhite" with Python and OpenCV?

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, opencv3.0

I am looking for a straightforward way of applying automatic white balance to an image.

I found some official documentation about a `balanceWhite()` method: [cv::xphoto::WhiteBalancer Class Reference](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/d9/d7a/classcv_1_1xphoto_1_1WhiteBalancer.html#ae23838a1a54f101b255bca1a97418aa3)

However, I have an obscure error when I try to call the function as shown in the example.

```
image = cv2.xphoto_WhiteBalancer.balanceWhite(image)
```

Raises:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Delgan\main.py", line 80, in load
    image = cv2.xphoto_WhiteBalancer.balanceWhite(image)
TypeError: descriptor 'balanceWhite' requires a 'cv2.xphoto_WhiteBalancer' object but received a 'numpy.ndarray'
```

If then I try to use a `cv2.xphoto_WhiteBalancer` object as required:

```
balancer = cv2.xphoto_WhiteBalancer()
cv2.xphoto_WhiteBalancer.balanceWhite(balancer, image)
```

It raises:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Delgan\main.py", line 81, in load
    cv2.xphoto_WhiteBalancer.balanceWhite(balancer, image)
TypeError: Incorrect type of self (must be 'xphoto_WhiteBalancer' or its derivative)
```

Did anyone succeeded to use this feature with Python 3.6 and OpenCV 3.4?

I also tried with derived classes `GrayworldWB`, `LearningBasedWB` and `SimpleWB` but errors are the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer can be found in the [`xphoto` documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/df/db9/namespacecv_1_1xphoto.html).

The appropriate methods to create the WB algorithms are `createSimpleWB()`, `createLearningBasedWB()` and `createGrayworldWB()`.

Example:

```
wb = cv2.xphoto.createGrayworldWB()
wb.setSaturationThreshold(0.99)
image = wb.balanceWhite(image)
```

Here is a sample file in the official OpenCV repository: [`modules/xphoto/samples/color_balance_benchmark.py`](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/blob/383a0061c42771d01da73a5dc87d59e50480abd6/modules/xphoto/samples/color_balance_benchmark.py)